# Gunicorn not starting even after succesfully configuring all files

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn, wsgi, bad-gateway

I am working on a particular Django project (Don't know if this makes a difference but the service provider is Hostinger).. The deployment of the same is to be done on a vps server with ubuntu in it. Using gunicorn and nginx is what I have planned , but I keep on running into

> 502 bad gateway error
> On poking around found that gunicorn is not starting

The following is the error received when I ran

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

Error :

```
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-02 07:53:47 UTC; 4 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 6153 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[6153]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute /root/Assistanza/Assistanza/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[6153]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/Assistanza/Assistanza/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 07:53:47 srv457341 systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

The following is my file structure :
[image]

The path to this is :
/root/Assistanza/Assistanza

The following is the service file of gunicorn:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon                                                                                                                                             Requires=gunicorn.socket                                                                                                                                                After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/Assistanza/Assistanza
ExecStart=/root/Assistanza/Assistanza/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          Assistanza.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~                                                                                                                                                                       ~
```

How do I solve this ?

Update : So the error was the gunicorn was not running right in the virtual environment. To solve this I installed a new virtual environment and then installed gunicorn in that and saw that `which gunicorn` gave me the path to the file/env/bin/gunicorn.

and changed the service file path to this new venv and all is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message states that `gunicorn` module isn't installed on your env.
Activate your env and execute these commands:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

you need to install gunicorn.

If you have already installed `gunicorn` you may use [while being in env]:

```
which gunicorn
```

If it shows your env path, then your env is all-correct if not the env may be corrupted. Consider creating new virtual environment by using:

```
deactivate
virtualenv env
```

and install the requirements...
If the error is still there consider checking the file path & permissions.

I recommend to go through this document:
[DIGITALOCEAN-UBUNTU1604](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Until there is a .sock file in your folder, your `gunicorn` isn't running fine.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: So on using the which gunicorn I got the following path :
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
So should i delete the entire env and create a new one in same place or try reinstalling gunicorn in env ?

Comment: If you have activated the env and then run this command then yes, if not then activate it and then enter this command...

Comment: I tried doing so same thing there

Comment: Alright so I did that and reinstalled gunicrorn in the new venv workeed out like a charm changed the service file and all seems to be going good , now just need to congfigure the static files , thanks a ton